# Block focus/select in a ReadOnly textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, block, blocking, readonly

Someone knows how to block the focus/select in a read-only textbox (ReadOnly = true), without using enabled = false?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not want to set `Enabled`?

Comment: It appears that you want a TextBox to behave as a Label.  That raises the question: Why not use a Label?

Answer (score 1):

Controls have a `GotFocus` Event. You can add an event handler for this event and give another control focus, for example by calling `Select()` on another control or by using `SelectNextControl`:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_GotFocus(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
 Handles  MyTextBox.GotFocus
    MyTextBox.Parent.SelectNextControl(MyTextBox, True, True, True, True)
End Sub
```

Alternately, you can create a custom control that inherits `TextBox` and set `ControlStyles.Selectable` to `False`.

```
Public Class NonSelectableTextBox Inherits TextBox
    Public Sub New()
         SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Setting `ControlStyles.Selectable` to false will make the `TextBox` mimic the behavior of other controls which have this bit set to `False`:

- Label
- Panel
- GroupBox
- PictureBox
- ProgressBar
- Splitter
- LinkLabel (when there is no link present in the control)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully why you would want that. A read only text box allows selection to allow users to copy the text in there for other purposes. What I assume from your question is that you don't want the `TextBox` to accept input focus when a user is tabbing through controls, which I've seen to be a more common requirement.

You can achieve this via code:

```
TextBox1.TabStop = False
```

to ensure that tab doesn't direct focus to the readonly textbox. You can also achieve this in the designer using the same property as the screenshot shows.

[image: Setting TabStop via the designer]